# Make a Webpage out of a 3D Cube ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, 3d

I´m trying to make a webpage out of a 3D cube with 6 surfaces/pages.

This is the Code of my 3D Cube:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('button').click(function(){
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  
  $('.ft').click(function(){                                    
    $('#shape').removeClass().addClass('show-ft');
  });
  
  $('.rt').click(function(){
    $('#shape').removeClass().addClass('show-rt');
  });
  
  $('.lt').click(function(){
    $('#shape').removeClass().addClass('show-lt');
  });
  
  $('.bk').click(function(){
    $('#shape').removeClass().addClass('show-bk');
  });
  
  $('.tp').click(function(){
    $('#shape').removeClass().addClass('show-tp');
  });
  
  $('.bm').click(function(){
    $('#shape').removeClass().addClass('show-bm');
  });
  
  $('.spinstart').click(function(){   
    $('#shape').addClass('spin'); 
  });
  
  $('.spinstop').click(function(){ 
    $('#shape').removeClass('spin'); 
  });
  
});
```

```css
#main { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  border:1px solid #ddd; 
  background-color:white; 
  width:800px; 
  height:500px;
  margin:10px auto; 
}

  .btn-group-wraper { 
        position:absolute; 
        top:30px; 
        left:65px; 
    }
  .shadow { 
        position:absolute; 
        width:100px; 
        height:100px; 
        box-shadow:0 0 15px white; 
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 155px white; 
        background-color:#000 !important; 
        opacity:.15 !important; -webkit-transform:    
          rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-100px);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-100px);    
    }
  #container { 
      width:100%; -webkit-perspective:800px; -moz-
        perspective:800px; 
      perspective:800px; position:relative; 
    }


  #shape {
   position:relative; margin:0 auto; top:170px;
      width:125px; height:125px;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(-30deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(-30deg);
       transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(-30deg);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
       transition: transform 2s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
   to  { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg)
      rotateY(360deg); 
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes spin {
   to  { 
      -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg); 
      }
  }
    @keyframes spin {
   to  { transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg); }
  }
  #shape > div { 
      position:absolute; 
      width:125px; 
      height:125px; 
      border:1px solid white; 
      background-color:#999;
    }
  #shape .ft { 
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(63px); 
      -moz-transform: translateZ(63px); 
      transform: translateZ(63px); 
    }
  #shape .rt { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(63px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(63px);
      transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(63px); 
    }
      #shape .bk { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg)
      translateZ(63px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(63px);
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(63px); 
    }
  #shape .lt { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(63px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(63px);
      transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(63px); 
    }
  #shape .tp { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(63px);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(63px);
      transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(63px); 
    }
  #shape .bm { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg)
      translateZ(63px); 
      -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) 
      translateZ(63px); 
      transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(0deg) 
      translateZ(63px); 
    }
    
  #shape.show-ft { 
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(63px); 
      -moz-transform: translateZ(63px); 
      transform: translateZ(63px); 
    }
  #shape.show-rt { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(-90deg);
      transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(-90deg); 
    }
  #shape.show-bk { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
      -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
      transform: rotateY(180deg); 
    }
  #shape.show-lt { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); 
      -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg); 
      transform: rotateY(90deg); 
    }
  #shape.show-tp { 
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
      -moz-transform: scale(1.5); 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-360deg);
      transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-360deg); 
    }
  #shape.show-bm { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(360deg);
      transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(360deg); 
    }
  #shape.spin { 
      -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear; 
      -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite linear; 
      animation: spin 5s infinite linear; 
    }
  #shape { 
      -webkit-transition: all 1s; 
      -moz-transition: all 1s; 
      transition: all 1s; 
      -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(-30deg);
      -moz-transform: scale(1); 
      -moz-transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(-30deg);
      transform: scale(1);
      transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(-30deg); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="btn-group-wraper">
      <div>
        <button class="ft">1</button>
        <button class="rt">2</button>
        <button class="bk">3</button>
        <button class="lt">4</button>
        <button class="tp">5</button>
        <button class="bm">6</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="spinstart">spin start</button>
        <button class="spinstop">spin stop</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="shape">
      <div class="ft" id="#ftid">1</div>
      <div class="rt" id="#rtid">2</div>
      <div class="bk" id="#bkid">3</div>
      <div class="lt" id="#ltid">4</div>
      <div class="tp" id="#tpid">5</div>
      <div class="bm" id="#ftid">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To the Fiddle.js:
[Fiddle.js](https://jsfiddle.net/nh30pLog/)

*Please ignore the `spinstart` and `spinstop`.*

To be honest this is not a selfmade code, I found it on a Website and downloaded it there.
As I had no idea about all that 3D stuff I started to learn it but
my knowledge about 3D cubes with css fails at the point optimizing the sizes of the cube.

I tried adding my sites into the:

```
<div id="shape">
  <div class="ft" id="#ftid">1</div>
  <div class="rt" id="#rtid">2</div>
  <div class="bk" id="#bkid">3</div>
  <div class="lt" id="#ltid">4</div>
  <div class="tp" id="#tpid">5</div>
  <div class="bm" id="#ftid">6</div>
</div>
```

The Problem about that was, when I do that the cube breaks, meaning it doesn´t rotate correctly anymore, I don´t know if it was because a webpage is bigger than just `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` although I changed the size of the surfaces to `auto` so they adapt to the webpage´s css.

**Maybe I could correct myself if you guys could give me a short explanation or 
pointer on this topic.**

Please don´t vote this Question down, I did not find anything similar to this topic on the web. I only found simplified examples and tutorials on 3D cubes.

**Note:**
I not asking for codes, I´m asking for help.

Comment: Putting an <iframe> inside each of the divs should have worked. Show the actual code you used to show pages. Or by _"I tried adding my sites"_ to mean you put the actual html of the pages in those divs? If so, that may be a problem as there could be numerous parts of your pages html that could interfere with the cube code

Comment: Then you will have to start over, and go through it more thoroughly. Meaning start with one page, add a little bit of the html you want in that side at a time continue until either you have a working side or it breaks. If it breaks just look at the last bit you added and see what could be causing the issue. Though it might just be easier to use an <iframe> instead of trying to put an entire site page's html into a div.

Comment: Just change the size (width, height) of your shape and side divs. Then change the `translateZ()` css properties to match half of that size. So for instance if you change the size to 300px by 300px your translateZ would be `translateZ(150px)`